# Partial update to more than one child in transaction

Tags: firebase

To write to an object, one uses `.set()`, and to update a child object (or a number of child objects) leaving other children untouched you use `.update()`.

Is there an update facility with transactions?

Example, I have an object: `{person:{name:'name',address:'address',age:'age}}`. I want to use a transaction to just update `age` and `address` but leave `name` intact.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think such a function exists. But you could roll something yourself, by copying all updated properties in the update function that you pass into `transaction`.

```
var personRef = new Firebase('https://myapp.firebaseio.com/person1');
var update = { address: '10 downing street', age: 42 };
personRef.transaction(function(person) {
  for (var prop in update) person[prop] = update[prop];
  return person;
});
```

Comment: This is correct. Since a transaction is guaranteed to fail if the data changes between receiving and writing it back, there is no need for an update() here. You can update the fields you want, and send back the entire object with confidence.